# Cutting string near space positions

Tags: python, arrays, string, line-breaks

I have an array of space positions for a given string like this:
[3, 7, 11, 18, 24, 29, 34, 45, 50, 55, 59, 67, 70, 75, 80, 84, 90, 93, 97, 108],
and I have an array of values which are the borders of the page, so I need to find a position in the string where there is a space and where it is close to some border value in a given range for example +/- 5 characters like here:
[37, 74, 111, 148, 185, 222, 259, 296, 333, 370, 407].
I create this like this:

`lower_and_higher_bounds = [i for i in range(37,444,37)]`

So for example the first value of the new array should give 34 because it is the best option close to 37, the next value would be 67 because it is the next best value close to 74 and so on. Ive tried a lot of things but it just doesn´t work. Either some txt parts are missing or the text goes over the border. Does anyone has any idea how I can approach this? Basically I just need to write a function which calculates the line breaks so that that it is not broken in the middle of the word.

```py
lower_and_higher_bounds = [i for i in range(37,444,37)]


def search_cut_positions(space_positions, search_value):
    length = len(space_positions)
    lower_bound = 0
    upper_bound = length - 1

    while lower_bound <= upper_bound:
        midpoint = (upper_bound + lower_bound) // 2
        value_at_midpoint = space_positions[midpoint]

        if search_value >= value_at_midpoint - 5 and search_value <= value_at_midpoint:
            return value_at_midpoint
        elif search_value < value_at_midpoint:
            upper_bound = midpoint - 1
        elif search_value > value_at_midpoint:
            lower_bound = midpoint + 1

    return None


def cut_and_display_string(col_position, row_position ,input_string, rows=12):
    # Find space positions
    stringlen = len(input_string)
    space_positions = [i for i in range(stringlen) if input_string[i].isspace()]
    cut_array = [0,37]


    for i in range(len(lower_and_higher_bounds)):
        space_position = search_cut_positions(space_positions, lower_and_higher_bounds[i])
        if space_position == None:
            cut_array.append(lower_and_higher_bounds[i])
            break
        else:
            cut_array.append(space_position)

    # Calculate vertical positions
    x_positions = [card_height - i for i in range(20, card_height, 10)]

    for i in range(len(cut_array) - 1):
        start = cut_array[i]
        end = cut_array[i + 1]
        chunk = input_string[start:end].strip()
        display_position = row_position + x_positions[i]
        c.drawString(col_position + 10, display_position, chunk)
```

Here is the repo for the full code:

https://github.com/Narachara/FlashCardCreator/tree/main

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html module might be useful if you are just trying to wrap text to specific length(s)

Comment: How comes 67 is the value for 74 yet you have 70? Why is 70 not the one close to 74?

Comment: Because I want to take the lowest possible value. Otherwise it could be that the total distance from one split to the next exceeds the characters possible for the line.

Comment: Knuth spent years perfecting this for Tex.  Don't assume it will be easy.

Comment: Who is Knuth? I realize that it isn´t as easy as I thought. I wish the reportlab hat an easier way to do this. Maybe in the paid version.

Comment: "Who is Knuth?"  That made my day.  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth

Comment: Lol, yeah, now you just need to choose an actual programming language.  They should have called this one _Jabberwock_.

Comment: @Reilas What do you mean? I don´t understand.

Comment: @Kauabanga, I was trying to make fun of _Monty Python_.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC you're just trying to find the nearest number in a list to a given value. After that you can use your threshold value of +/- 5 to filter.

```
import numpy as np
def closest(lst, K):
     # find the item in lst which is closest to K
     lst = np.asarray(lst)
     idx = (np.abs(lst - K)).argmin()
     return lst[idx]

threshold = 5
spaces = [3, 7, 11, 18, 24, 29, 34, 45, 50, 55, 59, 67, 70, 75, 80, 84, 90, 93, 97, 108]
out = []

for i in range(37,444,37):
  ret = closest(spaces, i)
  if abs(ret-i) <= threshold:
    out.append(ret)
out
```

Output:

```
[34, 75, 108]
```

Comment: Thats a smart approach however it is possible that the space_position array is shorter then the loop counter which results in index out of bound error. I would need to adapt it somehow.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to create a word-wrap, you can do it a much easier way. The below works by slicing the input on the desired width, and looking for the first space from the end. The space index becomes the slice point for the line. The paragraph is then updated from that slice point, and the process continues until the paragraph is empty.

`1` is added to width to include the possibility of `width` characters being immediately followed by space. In which case, the line would be completely full. The example also handles cases where a word is longer than the allowed width, resulting in the word being sliced at `width`, and continued on the next line.

```
def wrap_lines(para:str, width:int) -> list:
    lines = []

    while len(para):
        #remove left side whitespace / store length
        para = para.lstrip(' ')
        l    = len(para)
        
        #find first space from end of slice
        p = para[0:width+1].rfind(' ')
        
        #facts
        a = l <= width
        b = p > -1
        
        #bitbang facts to choice index
        # 0: there is no space
        # 1: remaining input is shorter than width
        # 2: nearest right-side space
        i = (b>a) << 1 | a

        #get the proper slice index
        p = (width, l, p)[i]
        
        #store line / update paragraph
        lines.append(para[:p])
        para = para[p:]
        
    return lines
    
def display_string(para:str, x:int, y:int, width:int) -> None:
    lines = wrap_lines(para, width)
    row   = len(lines)
    
    for line in lines:
        c.drawString(x + 10, row * 10 + y, line)
        row -= 1
```

Comment: The problem is that I need the exact index positions because I want to write the string to pdf with reportlab. And I need to calculate the line breaks myself:
c.drawString(col_position + 10, display_position, mystrng[start:end])

Comment: Thanks for the dedication. I posted the link to the repository so you can check the whole code. It makes more sense I guess.

Comment: @Kauabanga - I went to your repository and I still don't see any place where knowing space indexes is important. You should be able to basically drop my example in place of your `cut_and_display_string` method and adjust your call for my args. Keep in mind `width` is the amount of characters allowed on a line.

Comment: Yes works alsow thanks! I don´t really understand it but it works. Difference is now that the cards get filled with text from bottom to top and not from top to bottom, Because of the reportlab layout system. It starts at the bottom left of the page.

Comment: Okay thanks a lot! I will need to figure out the bitshifting stuff but it looks very interresting.

Comment: @Kauabanga ~ I have updated my answer to properly address decrementing rows.

Comment: Nice! Thank you a lot. May I ask how you have come to the idea of solving this with bitshifting stuff? i just started with programming and algorythms in general. I know that there is a book called Hackers delight where there is a lot of these bit algorythms. But Im still at the beginning of my journey.

Comment: @Kauabanga - It's not complicated. All I am doing is taking a bunch of true and false "facts", and using bitwise math to turn them into the desired int. In the case above we need either 0, 1 or 2. The logic I used can only create those numbers. `(b>a)` really means, if `b` is true and `a` is False because that's the only way `b` can be > `a` so, we can either have just `a` which would be 1, just `b` which is 1 (<<) shifted left once, resulting in 2 or neither which is 0. Bit banging the way I did above, is one way to write branchless programs (ie. no if/elif/else).